# 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

```
class SkyFileGroupPermissionResource(Resource):

    sky_file = fields.ForeignKey(SkyFileResource,'sky_file',null=False)
    group_id = fields.ForeignKey(SkyGroupResource,'group_id',null=False)
    expires_at = fields.DateTimeField(attribute='expires_at',null=False)
    cloud_url = fields.CharField(attribute='cloud_url')
    is_active = fields.BooleanField(attribute='is_active',default=False)
    new_devices_default_access = fields.BooleanField(attribute='new_devices_default_access',default=False)

    class Meta:
        queryset = SkyFileGroupPermission.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'file_group_permissions'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','delete']

    def apply_authorization_limits(self,request,object_list):
        return object_list.filter(sky_file__storage__user=request.user.skyuser)

    def get_object_list(self,request):
        return super(SkyFileGroupPermissionResource,self).get_object_list(request).filter(sky_file__storage_user=request.user.skyuser)
```

Why am I getting `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` tastypie on GET method, all my api's are working fine, except of one, which give me that error

this is traceback message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/gegham/django-tastypie/tastypie/resources.py", line 202, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/gegham/django-tastypie/tastypie/resources.py", line 433, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

  File "/home/gegham/django-tastypie/tastypie/resources.py", line 465, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File "/home/gegham/django-tastypie/tastypie/resources.py", line 1287, in get_list
    objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

  File "/home/gegham/django-tastypie/tastypie/resources.py", line 1097, in obj_get_list
    raise NotImplementedError()

NotImplementedError
```

Do yo have any Idea , why it give that??

Comment: Are you creating a sub class of a base class with an abstract method without overriding the method? That's why the NotImplementedError is thrown.

Comment: I'm making an edit which can help you understand your error better. Next time, please try to understand the traceback rather than just take it as an error message. Also we're here to help, so make it as readable as possible, so we can help you better :)

Comment: To help you understand, `NotImplementedError` means you have to implement a particular method in some class. In this case, You have to see the last trace message: it seems the `Resource` is missing a method called `obj_get_list`. So you have to somehow have this method. This method seems available in `ModelResource` as mentioned by @JoeyWillhelm. Good Luck, hope you can learn something here :)

Comment: Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Tastypie documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#Resource.get_object_list), `get_object_list()` needs to be implemented at the user level. This means that you should not call `super()` in the method.

If you were to use a `ModelResource` instead of a `Resource`, however, then a `super()` would be available for you to use.